# Is it good to use reflection API on access of private method and variable?

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I want to access a private method of class while writing Junit test cases.Is it good to use reflection API? Somewhere  I found that the reflection API is slow.P

Please give a suggestion.

Comment: When you need to access a private method for your Junit tests, then either your tests are badly designed or the tested class is. So if you have access to both, then rethink the structure of either the test or the tested class.

Comment: Accessing private methods, variables from an other class is never a good idea

Comment: @Jens what should i do to a write a Junit on private method

Comment: test the public methods, which uses the private methods or redesign your code

Comment: but that is not good to introduce a new method to write only junit test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should not need to access any hidden variable in your unit test. But if you have to, then one possibility is to use package-protected visibility (no modifier). That way, your unit test can read / write the field, as long as it resides in the same package as the class under test.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the approach is totally fine and, I guess, not uncommon for most projects that do thorough unit testing. The reflection API was probably created for exactly this purpose.

Why do you worry about the reflection API being slow? It only slows down your tests, it doesn't matter for the users at normal runtime. However, if your tests become too slow because of reflection API access, then just upgrade your development hardware. I don't think it can ever be a problem, even when you hit really large number of module tests in the millions.

Just don't change your actual non-testing program source code, like changing everything to public because you want to test it. This would actually be a very bad thing to do. You want a clean API and clean classes, so you don't want to expose everything.

Testing can, and usually does, have implications on your software architecture like encouraging a more loosely coupled architecture and therefore the use of architecture patterns like dependency injection. However, testing must not define your API. The API should just be what you think it ought to be, not what the unit tests need (which would probably be setting everything to public, which is obviously not what language designers intended, when they introduced modifiers like private or protected).

In later testing phases, however, like system testing, it is obviously no longer necessary to use reflection API, since you're just triggering the normal, public API of your code and observe/check the response. You usually don't want to go down into the code and check additional things in this testing phase. However, there might be certain circumstances, like checking for flags or very critical values that you want to double-check.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about your design. If you have to think about testing private methods your class probably do more that it should and violates SRP in some point. I'm strongly recommending you to create new classes with smaller responsibilities. It does not look like your class is well defined, so cutting it should be fine.

You can test your private methods using reflection but still - it is not good way for that.

Comment: I would like to challange "private methods violates SRP in some point" or correct me if I understood it otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice according to normal *programming flow* on java and on junit test especially, you need to verify system under test (your class) as same way you will be use it in your app. Reflection breaking class incapsulation.

If you want to test private methods of something you need to completely rearrange your development workflow and use test driven development. Example how to *test* private methods properly in **tdd** way. Assume we have class A and test for it:

```
class A {

    public int calculate() {
        //very complex code
        // 50+ lines of code
    }

}

class ATest {

    public void shouldCalculateComplexThing() {
        A a = new A();
        int answer = a.calculate();
        Assert.assertEquals(answer, 42);

    }

}
```

after that we mention that `calculate()` method is too big to understand in first look and we need to 
refactor it:

```
class A {

    public int calculate() {
        return calculateFirstPart() + calculateSecondPart();
    }

    private int calculateFirstPart() {
        //code
    }
    private int calculateSecondPart() {
        //code
    }

}
```

Because we have test to it we already have the same answer `42`, but we changed code and introduce private methods
and we don't need to test it because they tested through method `calculate()`. It is a right way to testing private fields, methods, and other class realization details in **tdd**

Comment: So a super talented tester shows up and finds that you need more unit tests. Maybe (s)he's a mathematician so (s)he knows better than you do that you overlooked a specific, interesting arithmetic condition. (S)he writes some more test cases and indeed there is a problem in "calculate()". Maybe not an exception, but it just silently returns a wrong value. How do you decide now if the problem lies within calculateFirstPart() or calculateSecondPart()? You COULD already have the information, if you tested the private methods in the first place. Unit testing is testing the smallest possible pieces!

Comment: @weiglt smallest possible pieces it's not implementation details. Testing private methods limit us to do refactoring because tests knows how we do things inside a class instead of verify only correct output of public contract. When code very complex we may refactor that complex methods to different classes and tests that classes separately.